# SpringMVC：Is there any custom Resolver available to resolve "RequestMapping" annotated method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Some of my `RequestMapping` annotated controller method are annotated with something like `@Authentication("user"/"admin")`. So I can now user aop to authenticate all the requests.

But now I am also using cumtomized `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`,  I want to resolve authentications before `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
@Authentication("user")
@RequestMapping("/xxx", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public getxxx(Token token) {
    System.out.println(token.getUserId());
}
```

Is that possible?

Edit:

`Token token` in the argument is not necessary. For example:

```
@Authentication("user")
@RequestMapping("/xxx", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public getxxx() {
    // do something authenticated "users" can only do
}
```

Comment: You wrote that you already use a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and you ask if it's possible???

Comment: No, I don't want to resolve authentications in `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, because `Token token` in the argument is not necessary as in some handler method this is not needed.

Comment: Spring Security already provides the [`@PreAuthorize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) annotation.

Comment: So you want the aspect to be executed earlier? Like it's done with using an interceptor?

Comment: @sp00m is that possible to recognize the `@Authentication("user")` in the handler method? Or else there will be no difference with registering a customized `javax.servlet.Filter`

Comment: @zeroflagL If it is possible to execute aspect earlier than `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, then this would solve the problem.

Comment: @zeroflagL It is bit like using a interceptor, but I need to know what value contains in `@Authentication("value")` for handler method, so that I can valid the authentication correspondingly

Comment: You can get the value using an interceptor as well.